# unable to locate adb error when i click run button

Tags: android, android-studio, adb, android-sdk-manager

when i click to install android platform tools it shows following image

[image]

when i click exit studio and launch sdk manager android studio is closing but sdk manager is not launching

If i try to attempt all packages the following image is occuring

[image]

please help me to fix this issue

Comment: the second image is seen for long time but installation is not happening

Comment: tried installing sdk by closing android studio ?

Answer (score 0):

Yah thats correct it will take time download and unzip all the downloaded files and then it installs on your system till that time you have to wait

Answer (score 0):

**`From installed Sdk Path(ex c:\sdk\ etc) -> launch SDK manager`**, try right clicking on the **`SDK Manager.exe`** and selecting "**Run As Administrator**". **close** all the instances of android studio before updating.and kill **`adb.exe`** also.

Also, some anti-virus programs have been known to interfere with SDK Manager

**SDK path**

If you're using android studio then...

1. Open the Android SDK Manager.
2. At the top of the window, just above the list of SDKs, it says "SDK Path: ".

mine is:

> **C:\Users\[account]\AppData\Local\Android\sdk**

[image: SDK Path]

Comment: where is the installed sdk path? I can't find it

Comment: i update the answer.yours is **C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Android\sdk**.mark it as answer if you find solution.

Comment: There is no AppData folder

Comment: how to see hidden files?

Comment: Research on internet..here we only give answers to programming problems. **welcome to SO**

Comment: after opening sdk folder from above path it has lot of folders in it.Which folder should i open

Answer (score 0):

You can try to launch Android SDK manager manually by launching **SDK manager.exe** . You can find its  location in windows by Android studio. Go to Menu option
**File-> Project Structure->SDK location**
[image]

If it give you any error on launching as per https://stackoverflow.com/a/39097281/4290570 , please feel free to comment further.